# How can I map a nested array from JSON?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, json, reactjs

Bear with me, I am not good with words, Here, I'll try my best to explain on my issues with mapping the nested data in array, I am guessing this term would be called "fetching data from local API with ReactJS" This code below is the data inside the data.js as "local API"

```
    export default[
    {
        name: "John Doe",
        position: "developer",
        experiences: [
            {   
                id: 0,
                job:"developer 1",
                period: "2016-2017",
                description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium nesciunt recusandae unde. Qui consequatur beatae, aspernatur placeat sapiente non est!" 
            },
            {
                id: 1,
                job:"developer 2",
                period: "2015-2016",
                description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium nesciunt recusandae unde. Qui consequatur beatae, aspernatur placeat sapiente non est!" 
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                job:"developer 3",
                period: "2014-2015",
                description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium nesciunt recusandae unde. Qui consequatur beatae, aspernatur placeat sapiente non est!" 
            }

        ]

    }
]
```

And the code below show two component files the index.js and App.js in ReactJS

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App'
import data from './data/dataJS';


ReactDOM.render(
     <App data={data} />, 
      document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
     const {data} = this.props;
      const resume = data.map(info => {

        //console log
        console.log(info.name);
        console.log(info.position);
        console.log(info.experiences);
        console.log(info.experiences.job);

        //browser render
        return (
          <div>
              {info.name}
              <br/>
              {info.position}

           </div>
          )
        });
      });

    return (
      <div>
          {<p>{resume}</p>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So far, I am able to fetch the data as confirmed from browser console.log and render out two data `info.name` into **John Doe** and `info.position` into **developer** without problem.

Now, If I added this string `<li key="experience.id">{info.experiences.job}</li>` beneath {info.position} I will get an error.

**Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, job, period, description}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

I assume, the way I set up array is incorrect. But the console.log of `info.experiences` shown result of (3) arrays of experiences. But The console log on `info.experiences.job` show undefined. Yet I am unable to figure out the what the problem are, what could be wrong?

I've spend two days trying to find solution and I am not any getting luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `info.experiences` is an array. `console.log(info.experiences)` should show you that. So to access the `job` property, you'd have to do `info.experiences[0].job` or something similar.

Comment: info.experiences[i].job

Comment: why you got 2 `return` in your `App` render?

Comment: @Sag1v One is inside of the `data.map`. It's turning `resume` into an array of elements.

Comment: you got syntax error there, after the first return you closed the `render` function

Comment: info.experiences[i].job or info.experience[0].job will work if i am using for() loop. But I am using map() unless you can show me it work on map.

Comment: run a loop on experiences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got couple of things to fix here:

- You got a syntax error in your `render` function, in the first
  `return` you closed the the `render` function body, hence you can't
  reach the second `return` (it shouldn't even render and throw an
  error).
- You are trying to reference an object in your key? you used a string.
  anyway keys should be unique to their siblings [DOCS](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

  `<li key="experience.id">{info.experiences.job}</li>`
- This should be (but hold your horses we are not done yet!):

  `<li key={experience.id}>{info.experiences.job}</li>`
- `experience` is undefined, i'm guessing you wanted to loop through
  `experiences` array:

  `info.experiences.map(experience => <li key={experience.id}>{experience.job}</li>)`

Anyway here is a running and working example:

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "John Doe",
    position: "developer",
    experiences: [
      {
        id: 0,
        job: "developer 1",
        period: "2016-2017",
        description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium nesciunt recusandae unde. Qui consequatur beatae, aspernatur placeat sapiente non est!"
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        job: "developer 2",
        period: "2015-2016",
        description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium nesciunt recusandae unde. Qui consequatur beatae, aspernatur placeat sapiente non est!"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        job: "developer 3",
        period: "2014-2015",
        description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium nesciunt recusandae unde. Qui consequatur beatae, aspernatur placeat sapiente non est!"
      }

    ]

  }
]


class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    const resume = data.map(info => {
      //browser render
      return (
        <div>
          {info.name}
          <ul>
          {
            info.experiences.map(experience => <li key={experience.id}>{experience.job}</li>)
          }
          </ul>
          {info.position}
        </div>
      );
    });

    return <div>{<p>{resume}</p>}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Edit**
As a followup to your comments:

> I almost never encounter any error except for when I try to assign it
>   on nested array

Well as for your code in the `render` method of `App.js`:

```
render() {
    // console.log(this.props.name)
     const {data} = this.props;
     const resume = data.map((info) => {
        return (
          <div>
             {info.name}
             {info.experiences.map((experience, idx)=> 
                  <div >
                      <div key={experience.id} >{experience.job}</div>
             </div>)}
             {info.position}

          </div>
      )
    });
```

You got 2 issues:

1. In first loop iteration you should pass a key to the root element as
   well, not only to the second loop.

   ```
   const resume = data.map((info, key) => {
               return (
                 <div key={key}>
                    {info.name}
                    // ...
   ```
2. In the second loop, you passed the key to the child element and not
   the parent element of this loop:

   ```
   {info.experiences.map((experience, idx)=> 
                     <div >
                         <div key={experience.id} >{experience.job}</div>
                </div>)}
   ```

   The key should be on the root element not the second element:

   ```
   {info.experiences.map((experience, idx) =>
               <div key={experience.id}>
                 <div>{experience.job}</div>
               </div>)}
   ```

Working example:

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: "resume",
    name: "John Doe",
    position: "developer",
    experiences: [
      {
        id: 0,
        job: "developer 1",
        period: "2016-2017",
        description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium nesciunt recusandae unde. Qui consequatur beatae, aspernatur placeat sapiente non est!"
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        job: "developer 2",
        period: "2015-2016",
        description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium nesciunt recusandae unde. Qui consequatur beatae, aspernatur placeat sapiente non est!"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        job: "developer 3",
        period: "2014-2015",
        description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium nesciunt recusandae unde. Qui consequatur beatae, aspernatur placeat sapiente non est!"
      }

    ]

  }
]

class App extends React.Component {


  render() {
    // console.log(this.props.name)
    const { data } = this.props;
    const resume = data.map((info, i) => {
      return (
        <div key={i}>
          {info.name}
          {info.experiences.map((experience, idx) =>
            <div key={experience.id}>
              <div>{experience.job}</div>
            </div>)}
          {info.position}

        </div>
      )
    });

    return (
      <div>
        {resume}
      </div>

    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App data={data} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**BONUS**
As for this comment:

> I would have used codepen, but realize but its not possible to create
>   two files i.e. index.js and App.js

You can use [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) it's great for react.
Here is a working example with your code in separate files [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/jnryxk9ovw).

Comment: It worked, but still encounter key id issues. Yes, the string with " " have been eliminated. I use { experience.id } any suggestion.

Comment: what do you mean by _"but still encounter key id issues"_? what kind of issues? it's working here though

Comment: Sorry for not being clear...After correcting following your suggestion, it solved problems. I am able to see data of array.map on page. At the same time, the browser console.log shows warning with unique ID. --> "proxyConsole.js:54 Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop."  it appear it has something to do with key={experience.id} not being recongized.

Comment: @sirrus React wants a way to keep track of each DOM element individually, so you need a `key` prop. Easy. Just use the index number argument that's built into `map`  `info.experiences.map((experience, idx) => <li key={experience.id} key={idx}>{experience.job}</li>`

Comment: I am not sure I get the idea about key={idx} but here is a image link show what appears on screen with chrome console.log https://www.dropbox.com/s/4iyq74ex5pavdlh/imgex.JPG?dl=0 hope this image can give you some clues. with this code `info.experiences.map((experience, idx) => <li key={experience.id} key={idx}>{experience.job}</li>` how do I apply second key`key={ ??}` or `key={idx}`

Comment: @sirrus `key` is a special prop for React that won't be shown in `console.log`. Does the code that I showed you not work? When you map over the array of elements, it should assign keys automatically one by one. So each `<li/>` will have a hidden prop of 'key' that is 0 for the first, 1, then 2 and so on. Iteration is an automated process, don't overthink it ;)

Comment: @Andrew... The code you showed `info.experiences.map((experience, idx) => <li key={experience.id} key={idx}>{experience.job}</li>` did not work... it strikes an error. 'No duplicate props allowed'. I think the second argument (idx) only assign on for() loop ??

Comment: My mistake. I didn't realize you added a `key` prop already. So key was declared twice. Whatever `experience.id` is. it's the same for every single element in your array and that's why you get that warning. Take out `key={experience.id}` and you should be fine.

Comment: Now that I look at it.. I don't know why `experience.id` wouldn't work. Try using `idx` as the key first. If the error disappears, then you might want to debug by `experience.id` never changes.

Comment: @sirrus as i wrote in my answer, your keys should be unique. you can read more about it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

Comment: @sag1v Yes I've read docs about unique key most of time and Always used this on most projects. I almost never encounter any error except for when I try to assign it on nested array. I have recent done a test, I placed same 'experience' list from nested array into normal array. And the result, react was able to assign unique key. Either way, I must have missed something for nested array or Its a bug in React. I went into google try to find example on assigning unique key on nested array with react. I haven't found any as of yet.

Comment: Nested arrays should work the same, i do it all the time. I will post an example soon

Comment: @Sag1v - "I will post an example soon" that would be very helpful... I appreciate that.

Comment: @sirrus That almost sounds impossible, so the issue may be with another set of data that you're using `map` over. Try commenting out that code and see if you still getting that error.

Comment: And post your data structure so we can see how your data looks like

Comment: @Sag1v - I've pushed my issues into github https://github.com/aprather51/fetch-data you can download or clone it. I would have used codepen, but realize but its not possible to create two files i.e. index.js and App.js to find the problems. Let me know

Comment: @Andrew, you try to clone from my github and see why I am having issues. The link is from Sag1v comment.

Comment: I see your problem, well you got 2 problems i will update my answer again

Comment: Hmm-- that got me wonder what was 2 problems. Looking forward to learn my mistakes.

Comment: @Sag1v - Any luck?

Comment: @sirrus i've already updated my answer yesterday. see the **Edit** section

Comment: @Sag1v - Now I can clearly see my what my issues are, I have made an note it for future. I understand,  Anytime I want to make loop iteration  should always assign unique key on any elements as a good practice. React wouldn't complain if it doesn't need it. As for Bonus feature you shared. This something I didn't know and does HELP me tremendously, now I can share codes among react peers. Thank you all for your effort and time. Hats off to you.

Comment: BTW after react update into version 16 few days ago... the document finally show lot better. https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys